# Is there an alternative to stats.zscore to detect outliers in dataframe with less than 10 rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I am trying to find a way to apply an algorithm designed to work with large dataframes to a very small dataframe, as the idea is to receive every row of data dynamically from a wireless sensor, and it should work for dataframes of only 2 or 3 rows.

A problem I have encountered is that the outliers detection method I use in the algorithm does not seem to work for dataframes that have less rows than 10.

The data I am using is from a .xlsx file that has three columns: "ID","Temperature" and "Date".
The outliers test I apply to my algorithm is the median absolute deviation:

```py
dfn=df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df['Temperature']))<4)]
```

The error message I obtain when trying to use the algorithm for 9 rows of data is as follows:

```py
/home/.../scipy/stats/stats.py:2419: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
 return (a - mns) / sstd
Metodo3in.py:20: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
```

Then the code executes anyway, but I obtain:

```py
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID,Temperature,Date]
Index:[]
```

**Questions**

- Why is 10 the minimum number of data rows for stats.zscore to work?
- Is there any alternatives that can be applied on smaller dataframes? Losing some precision IS an option.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide your dataframe? (not as image)

Comment: The question was answered, but thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stats.zscore` works for any length of input data greater than 1. Your issue occurs when all temperatures are equal. In this case the result of `zscore` is all `np.nan` which leads to the empty result dataframe as any comparison with `nan` yields `False`:

```
stats.zscore([1,1]), np.abs(stats.zscore([1,1])<4)
#(array([nan, nan]), array([False, False]))
stats.zscore([1,2]), np.abs(stats.zscore([1,2])<4)
#(array([-1.,  1.]), array([ True,  True]))
```

So you need an additional condition *"all values are equal"*  or'ed with *"abs(zscore)<4"*. The "or" operator for series is a bitwise "or" (`|`) which does not shortcut, i.e. the second operand is always evaluated even if the first is already `True`. This results in a warning (but the result is correct, as the second condition doesn't matter if the first is already `True`). To suppress this warning you need catch and ignore it:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    dfn = df[df.Temperature.eq(df.Temperature[0]).all() | (np.abs(stats.zscore(df['Temperature']))<4)]
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot. To clarify, should I include other warnings in the defined warning catcher?
I have pd.options.mode.chained_assignment=None active in code

Comment: I think as you have just this one statement in the warnings context manager it's OK to catch all. If you like you can add `RuntimeWarning` to the filter.